# Extract a date from a complex NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, date, nsstring

I don't have the ability in Xcode to resolve this problem:

I have this text:

"402
Garcia
01/08/15 10:26
Observaciones del huésped"

And i want to extract the date that i'm sure is GMT +0, then add the phone GMT for example GMT +1 and the replace that old date with the new date inside the NSString.

The GMT stuff i have just solve it in another place so i just need to extract and replace the date string in to the string so my final result will be something like:

"402
Garcia
01/08/15 11:26
Observaciones del huésped"

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is exactly what [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/index.html) is there for.

I made a method in a category on NSString:

```
@interface NSString (HASAdditions)

- (NSArray *)detectedDates;

@end


@implementation NSString (HASAdditions)

- (NSArray *)detectedDates {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDataDetector *dateDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
    if (!dateDetector) return nil;
    NSArray *matches = [dateDetector matchesInString:self options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)];
    NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if (match.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeDate) {
            [dates addObject:match.date];
        }
    }
    return dates.count ? [dates copy] : nil;
}
```

You can just call it like this:

```
NSArray *dates = [@"402 Garcia 01/08/15 10:26 Observaciones del huésped" detectedDates];
```

You can read more about NSDataDetector over on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/)

Answer (score 0):

This work is alway is the same text structure.

```
NSString *text = @"402 Garcia 01/08/15 10:26 Observaciones del huésped";

// This the formatter will be use.
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

// First we extract the part of the text we need.
NSArray *array = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[array objectAtIndex:2],[array objectAtIndex:3]];
// Here the search text
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);

// Now we use the formatter and the extracted text.
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"The date is: %@",[date description]);
```