# How to split date from string in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

How can I split only `"2017-09-10"` from strings like`"\u200c2017-09-10"`.

```
days = "\u200c2017-09-10" 
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
date = formatter.date(from: days)
```

date return `nil` when it is not split.

Comment: If you receive the same format then you can drop first 6 characters! or you can grab last 10 characters.

Comment: If there is more characters

Comment: How, plz provide code

Comment: If it’s an arbitrary string you can use an NSDataDetector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27861843/1489885

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
days = "\u200c2017-09-10"
let last10 = String(days.characters.suffix(10))
```

Output: `2017-09-10`

Basically you are just taking the last 10 characters of the string days.

Comment: if string is like "\u200c2017-09-10sfswe", then

Comment: If you are certain about the starting of the string then just use prefix instead of suffix: `String(days.characters.prefix(11))`

Answer (score 0):

You used string seprated function like this:-

```
 func SplitDatefromString() -> String {
            let getString = self.components(separatedBy: "-")
            guard getString.count != 0 else {
                 return "0"
            }
            return getString[0]
  }
```